# Substring without removing field character

Tags: awk, sed

I have a string that I want to substring in awk (or cut, or sed, whatever).

But I want to maintain the field separator.

The file has a completely random amount of junk after the field separator, of a random number of characters.

E.g.

Dogs.pgp.123sda
Dogs.pgpsjaksdasdasdaw
Dogs.pgp-asasdawad2

I want all three outputs to be:

Dogs.pgp

Obviously the common field here is ".pgp", but a standard awk always removes the field separator.

`'{sub(/.pgp.*/,""); print}'`

Or

`awk -F".PGP." '{print $1}'`

Is there a way to maintain the separator?

Comment: Yes. I intend to use regex to match all ending file types. Good addition.

Comment: Why not just manually stitch the 'separator' back on?  `sed 's/\.pgp.*/\.pgp/' file`

Comment: Or let sed do the stitching:  `sed  's/\(\.pgp\).*/\1/' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
for string in Dogs.pgp.123sda Dogs.pgpsjaksdasdasdaw Dogs.pgp-asasdawad2
do
    printf '%s --> %s\n' "$string" "${string%${string#*.???}}"
done
```

Output:

```
Dogs.pgp.123sda --> Dogs.pgp
Dogs.pgpsjaksdasdasdaw --> Dogs.pgp
Dogs.pgp-asasdawad2 --> Dogs.pgp
```

The loop iterates over the three strings. In the body of the loop, the original string is printed together with the transformed string.

The string is transformed by removing everything but the part before the first dot in the string and the three characters following the dot.

This is done by first figuring out what to remove from the original string. This is `${string#*.???}`, i.e. the rest of the string after removing up to the first dot and three more characters.  This is then removed from the end of the string through `${string%${string#*.???}}`.

If the loop iterated over *filenames* matching e.g. `*.pgp*`, then this would also handle the cases where the filenames contained newlines.  The only thing that would confuse the above transformation is if there were dots before the `.pgp` substring, but you could handle that by matching `.pgp` explicitly instead of `.???`:

```bash
for fname in *.pgp*
do
    printf '%s --> %s\n' "$fname" "${fname%${fname#*.pgp}}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
awk -F '.pgp' '{print $1 FS}'
```

I would be tempted to use `perl -pe 's/\.pgp\K.*//'` instead of awk.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved the issue using a match and a substring:

```
'match($0, /REGEX/) {sub(/REGEX/, substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) ); print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with awk substr method:

```
awk '{print substr($1,1,8)}' filename
```

The output is:

```
Dogs.pgp
Dogs.pgp
Dogs.pgp
```